# Populate into dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

This set of code below displays a list of selection in 2 level as shown in the picture

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AccessRequest.RoomCheckBoxes.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <li>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AccessRequest.RoomCheckBoxes[i].IsCheck, new { @class = "parent" })
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AccessRequest.RoomCheckBoxes[i].IsCheck, Model.AccessRequest.RoomCheckBoxes[i].SiteName + " - " + Model.AccessRequest.RoomCheckBoxes[i].RoomName)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AccessRequest.RoomCheckBoxes[i].RoomId)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AccessRequest.RoomCheckBoxes[i].RoomName)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AccessRequest.RoomCheckBoxes[i].SiteName)
                            <div class="racksfor" style="margin-left:20px;">
                                <ul class="suiterecord">
                                    @for (int j = 0; j < Model.AccessRequest.RoomCheckBoxes[i].Racks.Count; j++)
                                    {
                                        <li style="float:left;">
                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AccessRequest.RoomCheckBoxes[i].Racks[j].IsCheck, new { @class = "child chkboxCss" })
                                            <div class="ARSLabel">
                                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AccessRequest.RoomCheckBoxes[i].Racks[j].IsCheck, Model.AccessRequest.RoomCheckBoxes[i].Racks[j].RackName + " " + Model.AccessRequest.RoomCheckBoxes[i].Racks[j].Alias)
                                                @*@Model.AccessRequest.RoomCheckBoxes[i].Racks[j].Alias*@
                                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AccessRequest.RoomCheckBoxes[i].Racks[j].RackName)
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        if ((j + 1) % 5 == 0)
                                        {
                                        @:</ul><div style='clear:both'></div><br><ul class='suiterecord'>
                                        }
                                    }
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div style='clear:both'></div><br>
                        </li>
                    }
```

[image]

How do I change it to populate it as 2 dropdown list such that dropdownlist 1 = CO3 - Suite 80 and dropdownlist 2 will show the racks associate with the selected suite?

This controller returns the list of rooms to the front end

```
private List<RoomWithCheckBox> populateRooms(IEnumerable<int> selectedRoomIds, Int32? companyID = null)
    {
        if (selectedRoomIds == null)
            selectedRoomIds = new List<int>();

        var currentSession = Helpers.GetCurrentSession(User.Identity);
        var roomsResponse = repository.Rooms.GetAll(companyId: (companyID ?? currentSession.CompanyId));
        if (roomsResponse.Status == ReturnStatus.SessionInvalid)
        {
            throw new InvalidSessionException();
        }
        if (roomsResponse.Status == ReturnStatus.Success)
        {
            //return roomsResponse.Result.Select(x => new SuperAdminRoom
            //{
            //    RoomName = x.Name,
            //    RoomId = x.Id,
            //    IsCheck = selectedRoomIds.Contains(x.Id)
            //}).ToList();

            var Sar = new List<RoomWithCheckBox>();
            var Roomz = roomsResponse.Result.ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < Roomz.Count(); i++)
            {
                var rmz = Roomz[i];
                var Suite = new RoomWithCheckBox()
                {
                    RoomId = rmz.Id,
                    RoomName = rmz.Name,
                    IsCheck = selectedRoomIds.Contains(rmz.Id),
                    Racks = new List<RackWithCheckBox>()
                };
                if (rmz.Floor != null && rmz.Floor.Site != null)
                    Suite.SiteName = rmz.Floor.Site.Name;

                Sar.Add(Suite);
                foreach (var rackz in rmz.Racks)
                {
                    var CompanyRacks = new RackWithCheckBox()
                    {
                        RackName = rackz.ServiceId,
                        RackId = rackz.Id,
                        Alias = rackz.Alias,
                    };
                    Suite.Racks.Add(CompanyRacks);
                }
            }

            return Sar;
        }
        else if (roomsResponse.Status == ReturnStatus.NoRecords)
        {
            return new List<RoomWithCheckBox>();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(roomsResponse.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well for Windows programs, the ComboBox has an event that can be called when we select an item from the ComboBox, so it should have the same for web too?

On windows program as an example I will create it like this `this.comboBoxSelectDoc.SelectedIndexChanged += this.ComboBoxSelectDoc_SelectedIndexChanged;`

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your intent is to create cascading dropdownlist and setting up 2 `DropDownListFor` bound to 2 properties as first step:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AccessRequest.SelectedRoom, new SelectList(Model.Rooms, "RoomId", "RoomName"), "Select a Room", new { @class = "form-control" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AccessRequest.SelectedRack, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Then handle `onchange` event of first drop down list to insert related values into second drop down list:

```
$('#SelectedRoom').change(function () {
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetRacks", "ControllerName")';
    $.getJSON(url, { id: $(this).val() }, function (result) {
        if (!result) {
            return;
        }

        $('#SelectedRack').append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Select Rack'));
        $.each(result, function(idx, item) {
            $('#SelectedRack').append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
        });
    }
});
```

Finally, create a controller action which returns `JsonResult` and pass related rack items with room ID provided from first drop down list:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetRacks(int id) 
{
    // other stuff related to create list of racks here

    // assume 'ListOfRacks' has type of 'List<Rack>' which contains entire rack information
    var racks = ListOfRacks.Where(x => x.RackId == id)
                           .Select(x => new { Value = x.RackId, Text = x.RackName + " " + x.Alias });

    return Json(racks, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Note that using multiple `@Html.HiddenFor` helpers for each properties of `Room` (i.e. `RoomName` & `SiteName`) become unnecessary because you can get all of them just by querying based from `RoomId` value after form submission.

**Additional note:**

To combine 2 property values into single text, you can use same technique for concatenating property values of `RackName` and `Alias` as shown below:

```
// assume 'Rooms' hold collection of all available rooms
model.RoomsList = new SelectList((from room in Rooms
                                  select new {
                                      RoomId = room.RoomId,
                                      RoomName = room.SiteName + " - " + room.RoomName 
                                  }),
                                  "RoomId",
                                  "RoomName",
                                  null);
```

Then pass `SelectList` instance above into first drop down list:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AccessRequest.SelectedRoom, Model.RoomsList, "Select a Room", new { @class = "form-control" })
```